# Latency occuring between typing the character and printing on screen on a Dell Inspiron m101z?

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, performance, dell

i am facing a bit problem with my laptop dell inspiron m101z and the problem is there is slight latency occurring in typing the text on keyboard and getting up same on the screen.
also sometimes i feel that my system is performing slow.

my configuration is :-

- 4gb RAM ddr3
- 320 hardisk
- amd athlon II k125

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at top, lsof, other performance tools to see what's running. It could be that your resources are just maxed out. It could also be an issue with your desktop manager of choice. More information will be needed before this can be definitively answered.

Comment: when the ubuntu install was fresh at that time the system was behaving normally .... i have huge application installed like Eclipse , netbeans and two three more stuffs like those ...